# Removing an object from a list in Python. (ProblemSetQuestion). Code not achieving results

Tags: python, python-3.x

Winkleson here looking for some help on a very simplistic question... I'm pretty out of it at the moment but I'd like to figure out what I am doing wrong with this problem :) Of course anyother methods to solve the problem would be excellent! Thankyou in advance!

Question:

---

> **Remove Item**
>
> Create a function that takes a list and a value and returns a list
> with all occurrences of the given value removed.

Pretty simple right? My head is going to hurt when I facepalm... Anyways here are the calls.

Calls:

---

```
>>> remove(['a','b','c','d','e'],'e') 
['a','b','c','d'] 
>>> remove([4,2,7,6,7,8,3,1,3,5],3) 
[4,2,7,6,7,8,1,5] 
>>> remove([4,4,4,4],4) 
[] 
>>> remove([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'hi') 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

My Code:

---

```
def remove(l,o): #l is list, o is object
    for i in l:
        if i == o: #If the current item is the object to be removed...
            l.remove(o) #Remove the object      
    return l #Finally return the list.
```

So... Here's the issue:

---

Call: remove([4,4,4,4],4)

Supposed to return:[]

What is returned: [4, 4]

Correct: False

---

So... If anyone out there knows what's going on it would be great if you were to share your knowledge! Furthermore any other methods of solving would be great as well. Hints would also be great if they aren't too vague. Anyways, Thanks in advance! - Winkleson

P.s. I'm still a beginner programmer so please don't be too hard on me :P Thanks alot!

Comment: A) Get indexes. Remove from right to left ; or B) Build new list with things you want only

Comment: @JBernardo, option A is O(n**2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to iterate over the list at the same time you're changing the list. In the first iteration:

```
l = [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Python looks at l[0], and deletes it.

Now the list is:

```
l = [4, 4, 4]
```

Since it just did l[0], Python now wants to look at l[1]. But since the list has changed, the value that used to be at l[1] is at l[0] instead, and gets skipped.

One option is to build a new list as you go:

```
def remove(l,o):  
    new_list = []  
    for i in l:        
        if i != o:
            new_list.append(i)       
    return new_list
```

Since this is a common sort of operation, Python lets you do the same thing with "list comprehensions", which are very handy:

```
def remove(l,o)
    new_list = [item for item in l if item != o]
```

(As a side note, it's generally a bad idea to use 1-letter variable names. It's an *especially* bad idea with "o" and "l", which can easily be mistaken for "0" and "1", respectively.)

Comment: It now makes complete sense :P  Also I know I just thought I could rush code the problem as I have multiple questions to get through in a small amount of time (I normally name my lists with l and a num) or as list1, list2, etc. Anyways thanks again!

Comment: Ok one small problem with your code... Your appending o to new list instead of i :P Therefore your just attaching the object you want to remove from the list and returning it XD Just a heads up :D

Answer (score 2):

Removing items one at a time with `list.remove()` is not efficient as the remaining elements need to be moved along the list each time you call remove(). Creating a new list with just the elements you want is much more efficient, and avoids the problem of modifying the list while looping over it.

This variant modifies the list in place as you are doing in your question

```
def remove(L, o):
    L[:] = (item for item in L if item != o)
    return L
```

the non-inplace variant returns a new list

```
def remove(L, o):
    return [item for item in L if item != o]
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't completelty understand your code however... (also I believe that your not using L in the right context (as a constant) I do know what your gettting at.. Thanks again!

Comment: @Winkleson, You are modifying the list in your attempt. If you don't wish to modify the list, just `return [item for item in L if item != o]` The square brackets mean it is a list comprehension rather than a generator expression

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate a list while looping over its elements. http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/ explains why.

Make a new list using a list comprehension and return that: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: OMG I forgot that I was working with immutable lists -_- I needed to create a new list and append the remaining values... ARGH. Thanks man!

Comment: You're not actually working with immutable lists. You *can* mutate at the same time as you iterate, it's just a very bad idea.

Comment: @PeterBB Yeah because it's skipping over the next list due to the shift in values right?

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the list at the same time as iterating over it.  This means that the list iterator is likely to get out of sync with the underlying list.

At the start, the list looks like this:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4]
 ^-iterator
```

When checking the first element, the iterator has moved to the next element:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4]
    ^-iterator
```

When calling `remove` (note that this behaviour is not guaranteed):

```
[4, 4, 4, 4]
 ^  ^-iterator
 |
 `this item is removed
```

After calling `remove`:

```
[4, 4, 4]
    ^-iterator
```

Also, implementing `remove` in terms of `remove` is unlikely to gain you many marks.  Try building a *new* list which contains just the appropriate items.

Answer (score 1):

you're very close, but it may be better to create a new list rather than just use the `remove` function, ie,

```
def remove(l,o): #l is list, o is object
    newlist = []
    for i in l:
        if i != o: #If the current item is the object to be removed...
            newlist.append(i)      
    return newlist #Finally return the list.
```